# how can you convert an ASCII value from another database into an integer column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

how can you convert an ASCII value from another database into an integer column into SQL server? I'm importing the data using the data wizard and then trying to convert
I need to update each column in the table to its unique number.... I don't know how to do this

Comment: What do you mean?  Are you wanting to convert an `A` to `65` or are you wanting to convert a `'65'` to a `65`?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to run it as a stored procedure when new data is added to the database. But, to convert to an int when inserting, this should help:

`INSERT INTO newTable newColumn SELECT (CAST oldColumn AS INT) FROM oldTable;`